# Integer solutions of $a^b+b^a+1=3ab$

Tags: number-theory

“Find all positive integer solutions $(a,b)$ for which $a^b+b^a+1=3ab$”

I do not have much of a concept of how to solve these kinds of assignments. Anyway, I tried to look for divisibility conditions, but I just got $b|a^b+1$ and because of symmetry $a|b^a+1$, and $3|a^b+b^a+1$

My main problem is that I cannot factor here well enough to make the problem simpler, which makes me kind of stuck here.

Comment: Hint: Here you can limit the size of the possible solutions reasonably easily - suppose $a\ge b \gt 3$ then $a^b\gt a^3 \gt 3ab$

Comment: Why should $b>3$? $(1,1)$ for example is a (trivial) solution as well!

Comment: Ah, now I got it. Nevermind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easiely see: If $a>3$ or $b>3$ then this equation can not be fullfilled.

So lets check
If $a$ or $b$ is zero you get $1=0$ thus this is no solution

- Case 1: $a=b=1$ then $1^1+1^1+1=3*1*1$ is a solution
- Case 2: $a=1$ $b=2$ or vice versa then $1^2+2^1+1=3*1*2$ is no
  solution
- Case 3: $a=b=2$, then $2^2+2^2+1=3*2*2$ is no solution
- Case 4: $a=2$ and $b=3$ or vice versa then $2^3+3^2+1=3*2*3$ is a solution
- Case 5: $a=1$ and $b=3$ or vice versa then $1^3+3^1+1=3*1*3$ is no solution
- Case 6: $a=b=3$ then $3^3+3^3+1=3*3*3$ is no solution

Thus only case 1 and 4 give you a solution

Comment: I can easily see (from Mark Bennet's comment) that the equation can't be fulfilled if **both** $a$ and $b$ are greater than $3$, but I don't easily see it if only one of them is so assumed.  What am I simply not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to get the solution set.

If $a=b$, then

$$1=3a^2-2a^a\implies a\text{ divides }1\implies a=1$$

which does, indeed, give a solution, $a=b=1$.

By the symmetry between $a$ and $b$, it suffices to look for solutions with $a\gt b$.

Now if $b\ge3$ were part of a solution, then $a\gt b$ implies

$$3a^2\gt3ab=a^b+b^a+1\ge a^3+3^a+1$$

which implies

$$0\gt a^2(3-a)\gt3^a+1\gt0$$

which is a contradiction, so we can conclude that $b=1$ or $2$.

For $b=1$, the equation becomes $a+1+1=3a$, which gives the solution $a=b=1$ again (except we're assuming $a\gt b$ at this point).

For $b=2$, the equation becomes $a^2+2^a+1=6a$, which can be rewritten as

$$(a-3)^2=8-2^a$$

Since the left hand side is non-negative, we must have $8\ge2^a$, which means $3\ge a\gt b=2$, leaving only $a=3$ as a possibility, which indeed is a solution.

In all, we have $(a,b)=(1,1)$, $(3,2)$, and $(2,3)$ as the possible solutions.